# uncaught typeerror object has no method 'insertafter'

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to add button inside the `div` the `div` element when i'm click to a button.
The following `JS` code:

```
function doThis(){
    var btn= document.createElement("input");
    btn.type="submit";
    btn.value="button";
    var child=document.getElementById("child");
    var submit=document.getElementById("submit");
    child.insertAfter(btn, submit);
}
```

and `html` markup:

```
<div id="parent" class="parent">
    <div id="child" class="child">
        <input type="text" class="text"/>
        <input id="submit" type="submit" onclick="doThis()"/>
    </div>
<div>
```

In console i have error message: `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDivElement> has no method insertAftert`. How to fix this?[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/bundos/BYwz9/)

Comment: you can use `child.appendChild(btn);`  http://jsfiddle.net/BYwz9/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no insertAfter, use insertBefore instead.

```
 submit.parentNode.insertBefore(btn, submit.nextSibling);
```

if submit is the last Child, then submit.nextSibling is null, and insertBefore will just append it to the parentNode.

http://jsfiddle.net/rooseve/BYwz9/1/